# Facebook Login Not defining Function

Tags: javascript, facebook

So I found a tutorial on Facebook Login Integration at: `http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/facebook-login-integration-website`

I followed it step by step and Google Chromes Developer Tools give me an error after clicking `Facebook Login` saying:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function index.php:53
onclick`

The button html is like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href='#' onclick='login();'>
      <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
      Facebook Login
</a>
```

The script is as follows, I really can't tell what is wrong because the function is defined within the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
         appId      : ' 163289720517425', // App ID
         channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
         status     : true, // check login status
         cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
         xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
       });
    };
    // logs the user in the application and facebook
    function login(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
         if(r.status === 'connected'){
                window.location.href = 'php/fbconnect.php';
         }else{
            FB.login(function(response) {
                    if(response.authResponse) {
                  //if (response.perms)
                        window.location.href = 'php/fbconnect.php';
                } else {
                  // user is not logged in
                }
         },{scope:'email'}); // which data to access from user profile
     }
    });
    }
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function() {
       var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
       e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';                
       document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Did you install the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure of the problem you're having here....cuz even when I boiled it down to just the function with an alert....it still didn't work???? Meaning it had nothing to do with facebook.

Anyways....this is how I would do it....

You're doing a cross domain request...so you have to register your domain....

Also....FB provides a javascript SDK, so no need to use both PHP and Javascript as you were trying...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '163289720517425',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms!!
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

$('.btn-success').click(login);

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
 (function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 function login(){
 FB.login(function(response) {
 if (response.authResponse) {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
  });
 } else {
  console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
 }
 });}
```

Comment: Ok, that appears to have made it work, It doesn't look like i'm close to being done making it fully functional yet. i.e. redirecting the user to the dashboard and putting his/her information into my database.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll just wait for you to get off.